# SELECT INTO Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table A:

```
ServerName, InstanceName, GroupName, Value1 (Some servers have more than 1 instance, therefore some servers are listed more than once) (400 records)
```

Table B:

```
ServerName, GroupName (100 records)
```

First I would like to insert `GroupNames` from Table B into Table A where `ServerName` exists in Table B. Then I would like to remove all servers from Table A that  do not have a `GroupName` so as to end with only 100 records in Table A, with `GroupNames` added.

Sample Data

Table A :

```
ServerName      InstanceName     GroupName          Value1
----------------------------------------------------------
Server1         Instance 1        -                 500
Server1         Instance 2        -                 300
Server2         Instance 1        -                 400
```

Table B :

```
ServerName      GroupName
-------------------------
Server1         Group1
Server2         Group2
```

Because there are a different number of records in each table, a simple `SELECT INTO` does not work.

Comment: Different number of records? Don't you mean different number of columns?

Comment: So, you want to UPDATE table A?

Answer (score 0):

First you should to update `TableA.GroupName` from TableB. Try to use this:

```
update A
set    A.GroupName = B.GroupName
from   TableA TAB
       inner join TableB B on A.ServerName = B.ServerName
where  ISNULL(A.GroupName,'-') = '-';
GO
```

Then you can remove all records that do not have `GroupName`

```
delete from TableA where ISNULL(GroupName,'-') = '-';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The update query is fine in previous answer but delete once can be modified more.

```
UPDATE TA
SET    TA.GroupName = TB.GroupName
FROM   TableA TA
       INNER JOIN TableB TB ON TA.ServerName = TB.ServerName

DELETE TA
FROM   TableA TA
WHERE TA.ServerName NOT IN(SELECT ServerName FROM TableB)
```